# How to add image icons in material design navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) example for navigation drawer. Now I am able to display text and I also set icons, but icon is not visible. Can any one help me with that? What is the issue with that code:

FragmentDrawer.java

```
public class FragmentDrawer extends Fragment {

    private static String TAG = FragmentDrawer.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter;
    private View containerView;
    private static String[] titles = null;
    private static int[] icons = null;
    private FragmentDrawerListener drawerListener;

    public FragmentDrawer() {

    }

    public void setDrawerListener(FragmentDrawerListener listener) {
        this.drawerListener = listener;
    }

    public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData() {
        List<NavDrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            NavDrawerItem navItem = new NavDrawerItem();
            navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
            navItem.setIcon(icons[i]);
            data.add(navItem);
        }


        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // drawer labels
        titles = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);
        icons=getActivity().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflating view layout
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

        adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        return layout;
    }


    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

    }

    public static interface ClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view, int position);

        public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }


    }

    public interface FragmentDrawerListener {
        public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="Profile"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in your "setUp" function to add this code.

Comment: I will post answer to this

Comment: @UmerKiani bro i need help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428715/how-to-store-items-of-multiple-json-array-and-display-it-listview

Answer (score 1):

use this code to change navigation icon

```
drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_nav);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    });
    drawerToggle.syncState();
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this works for you. please change your **setUp** function like this.

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
    containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

   //add here this code
   toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.iv_menu);


    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but read question carefully..its not about tool bar..i am talking about navigation drawer

Comment: please approve my answer.